# cannot update php on ubuntu 16.04 from php7.1.2 to php 7.1.3

Tags: magento2, php-7

I have a magento 2.2.2 and want to update to magento 2.3. The problem is my version of php. Currently I have php7.1.26 while magento 2.3 is compatible only with php 7.1.3+. The solution seems easy: upgrade my php version to 7.1.3. My problem is that I cannot find a way to do this.

I first tried the usual way with the update command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.1
```

This switched my php version from php7.1.14 to php7.1.26. But I need php7.1.3 so this is not good. So I tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1.3
```

but this installed php7.2 instead. I need php7.1.3 so this is not good either.

So my question now is:

Is there a way to have a php version 7.1.3+ but not 7.2+ ?

Thanks

Comment: I think some links can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619312/switch-php-versions-on-commandline-ubuntu-16-04 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, however I don't see how they might be helpful. The first link is to switch between two different installed php version but my problem is that I cannot even install the version of php I want. The second link just give me the procedure to install the php version I want, but I've already tried it and it doesn't work: this procedure gave me php 7.1.26 but I need the 7.1.3